# Birthmarks - What are they?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, reincarnation

I personally have a Mongolian birthmark that consumes half my chest and right leg. I've heard of Mongolian birthmarks being indicators of someone being Jewish. But otherwise, it's just a mark.

Browsing online I saw this quote:

> If it's true about birthmarks being the spot where you were killed in
>   your previous life then I feel bad for whoever Caesar reincarnated is

I messaged the guy and he claims it's a joke and theres no source. Doesn't even believe in reincarnation. Thinking about it all now, it makes sense going back to Cain and Abel.

So what does Judaism have to say about birthmarks? Is the quote above true to some extent?

Answer (score 6):

It has been quoted in the name of The Great Rebbe Moshe Tetelbaum of Uhel, Author of [YISMACH MOSHE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Teitelbaum_(Ujhel)), that he said he remembered the different *gilgulim* (incarnations) which he had been in in his past lives. He is quoted to have said that in his first *gilgul* he lived as one of the sheep in the flock of *Yaakov Avinu*, and that he added that and once Yaakov had hit him with a strap for going out of line, and that he still **had a mark on his shoulder**, which he showed to his students, which was caused by the said lash from Yaakov's strap

[image: HERE]

(And some say that he remembered the tune that Yaakov sang while leading his flock).

**This does not mean to say that every birthmark, Mongolian or other, is a sign of reincarnation, It is just an example of one such mark which told the story of the bearers incarnation.**

Comment: BTW does anyone know an online copy of _Yismach Moshe?_ Would be nice to edit in...

Comment: @Kazibácsi The said story is not written in the Sefer YM itself, but was quoted by many of his disciples, as quoted in the attached article. Others add that the YM said that he remembered being at Har Sainai, and He remembered the argument between Korach and Moshe, and some add that he lived during, and remembered the churban of the second Bais Hamikdash.